# How can I run `hackxor` inside VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I've found hacking game **[hackxor](http://hackxor.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/index.pl)**, but it's made for vmware.

I don't have any experience with vmware and I don't want to install it in my machine.

So I'd like to run **hackxor** inside VirtualBox if it is possible.

Comment: Erm... did you at least try to import it in VirtualBox? It's supposed to be able to use vmware images.

Comment: @Mat  
I tried, but VirtualBox can import only Open Virtualization Format

Comment: Making a new VM and selecting to use the existing vmdk works for me. Interestingly enough, when you type in the name "hackxor" in the new VM screen, it will automatically choose Fedora 14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not download it and not sure if this is everything but you should be able to get started with it. The most important part is that you are able to use the provided disk image.

VirtualBox supports vmdk (Vmwares image format) out of the box. So you should be able to directly use the provided disk image with VirtualBox. If this does not work have a look at the [VirtualBox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#vdidetails).

If this does not work you can also convert the disk image with `qemu-img`. Something like:

```
qemu-img -f vmdk -O vdi input_file output-file
```